# Can we use Red5 be used for streaming in android devices

Tags: video-streaming, red5, wowza

i have to build a video streaming app for android .can i use red5?? is its streaming work only for flash not for any other device ?? please suggest should i use wowza or red5 ??

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
because of small statement i am unable to post thats why i am using these extra a's sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza Media Server supports `rtsp streaming protocol` which can be used by android device to play videos.

[Click here](http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html) to view an example.

Comment: Yeah, but they don't provide any maintained client libraries for Android.